# ZenDesk find user by email

Tags: zendesk

How do you search to see if a user exists in ZenDesk? I've tried the following, where mydomain is the domain of my company:

Example: 
https://mydomain.zendesk.com/api/v2/users/search.json?query=myname@mydomain.com

This is documented in their API: http://developer.zendesk.com/documentation/rest_api/users.html#search-users

However, I am getting a 404 {"error":"InvalidEndpoint","description":"Not found"} as the response.

Comment: The API endpoint is correct, I have just tested and it works fine. Are you sure you have authenticated before requesting?

Answer (score 9):

Its simple, just do:

```
https://mydomain.zendesk.com/api/v2/users/search.json?query=email:myname@mydomain.com
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

We've put together a useful [nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ZendeskApi.Client/) if you're working with C#.

You can use the package to create a ZendeskApiClient:

```
IZendeskClient client = new ZendeskClient(
    new Uri("my-zendesk-api-host-endpoint"),
    "my-zendesk-username",
    "my-zendesk-token"
);
```

Then you can use the Search resource to find users:

```
var response = client.Search.Find(new ZendeskQuery<User>().WithCustomFilter("email", "usersEmail"));
```

Have a look at our blog for more [detail](http://tech.just-eat.com/2014/09/19/opensourced-the-zendeskapiclient).

Answer (score 2):

This is how to do it with the [Zendesk PHP API Client Library](https://github.com/zendesk/zendesk_api_client_php):

`$client->users()->search(array("query"=>"example@email.com"));`

Answer (score 2):

```
https://mydomain.zendesk.com/api/v2/users/search.json?query=email:myname@mydomain.com
```

In case email consist special chars (my+name@mydomain.com) it wont work.
But urlencode can help.

Answer (score 0):

Though a v late response but might be helpful for someone in future.

Please make sure that you make proper use of POST, PUT and GET accordingly. I got an error

Array([error] => InvalidEndpoint, [description] => Not found)

while coding which was because I was using POST instead of GET while searching user in Zendesk using API.

Here is a v helpful article too on adding/updating users to Zendesk
[Zendesk API Implementation In Codeigniter](http://foreachphp.com/zendesk-api-implementation-in-codeigniter/)